# How to display a modal and still have the page header in place?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi dear React developers. 
I really love Yahoo website on desktop (https://www.yahoo.com/). When you click on a post title, the post displays itself in a modal like page. The page header is still in place, you can scroll the content and in the top right corner, you can click a close button to dismiss the modal. The page url and title change in the address bar and the title bar. I think it is a very good idea from UX point of view. User can come back to blogposts list without going back and forth in navigation history.
I’m willing to achieve that exact kind of design to my project. I’m using Material Design Bootstrap for React UI package (https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/), but their Modal Component (https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/modals/basic/) is not that smooth and couldn’t get me the same results. Could anyone give me ideas as how to do it or suggest me some packages? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks joshmatt. I came across this package which did the job perfectly: https://github.com/wiloke1/wil-react-modal.

Answer (score 0):

One way I know how to do this is using Material-UI Drawers documented here:
https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/

Combining **Persistant Drawer** and **Clipped drawer** can give you this effect.
Here's a mock up of the idea:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-42stk?fontsize=14